# What is the purpose of passing a type to this class?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In the [Angular doc's cookbook for dynamic forms](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form#question-model), this base class for a question (one of their form elements) is recommended:

```
export class QuestionBase<T> {
  value: T;
  key: string;
  label: string;
  required: boolean;
  order: number;
  controlType: string;
  type: string;
  options: {key: string, value: string}[];

  constructor(options: {
      value?: T,
      key?: string,
      label?: string,
      required?: boolean,
      order?: number,
      controlType?: string,
      type?: string
    } = {}) {
    this.value = options.value;
    this.key = options.key || '';
    this.label = options.label || '';
    this.required = !!options.required;
    this.order = options.order === undefined ? 1 : options.order;
    this.controlType = options.controlType || '';
    this.type = options.type || '';
  }
}
```

And when it is used, a piece of type data is passed in

```
export class TextboxQuestion extends QuestionBase<string> {/* input-type specific code */}
                                                  ^^^^^^
export class DropdownQuestion extends QuestionBase<string> {/* input-type specific code */}
                                                   ^^^^^^
```

I don't understand why you would pass this type to the `QuestionBase` class. Broadly, why is it useful to pass a type to a class like this? And in this specific example, why pass the type of an optional property (not sure that it matters it is optional), and furthermore for HTML inputs, they all return strings as far as I'm aware, so what is the purpose?

Comment: "*And in this specific example, why pass the type of an optional property*" the property is **mandatory**. It's only optional for the object that the constructor accepts. Also, why do you think it can only be a string? I'll look around but `QuestionBase<number>` or `QuestionBase<"Yes" | "No">` seem quite valid to me.

Comment: [`QuestionBase<number>`](https://github.com/Hurence/logisland.historian/blob/master/historian/frontend/src/app/shared/dynamic-form/question-number.ts)

Comment: @VLAZ I'm missing something here then. How can it be mandatory, but also "optional for the object that the constructor accepts"?

Comment: `value: T;` is in the class properties. `value?: T` is in the options that are passed in. So, it's valid to pass `{}` into the constructor - it's an object which doesn't have the `value` property. It's invalid to *not* have the `value` property on the actual object you're working with which *has* that constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way of writing generics in [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

HTML inputs used with Angular Forms can handle far more than `string`, if you have `<input type="number">` it will not return a string but a `number` for example. That's maybe what you're missing here.

Comment: [`type="number"` still produces a string](https://jsbin.com/tipoheroxu/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Then that's not `<input type="number">` you are talking about something different. The HTML element *only* produces strings.

Comment: I edited my answer to be more precise, but I guess the answer context was implied from the question context. Thanks for the precision though.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understood that a generic is being passed to the class. My question is, what value does it provide? If it is valuable, why is only one type passed to the class for this optional property and not all of those properties.

Comment: @1252748 why would you pass the types of *all* those properties? What sense does it make for `required` to be, for example, an array or a number? Why would you want `order` to be an HTMLElement or a boolean? Do you really need `type` to be an object with Symbol keys and values that are recursively the same kind of objects?

Comment: @VLAZ OK so it's useless for all those properties, why is it useful for `value`?

Comment: @1252748 because `required` can *only* be a boolean. It's either required or not. The value, however, might be a variety of things - maybe a number, maybe a union type of string strict values like `"Yes" | "No"` maybe something else. Your question is fundamentally "why use generics", it's not really about this particular class. So, I'd suggest reading more about those. There is a plethora of materials in different languages, including Java, and C# - they'd also be useful in explaining generics as the concept is the same outside TypeScript.